# Jquery Ajax issue from book

Tags: jquery

I am using a book to learn javascript, and I am in one of the final chapters where it teaches ajax with jquery. The example from the book does not work. I have even downloaded the file from a site I found that it had it uploaded by the author and checked. It will only pop up the alert when I try to submit the form. Here is the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ajax Form Submission</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            function checkFields(){
                return ($("#name").attr("value") && $("#email").attr("value"));
            }
            $("#form1").submit(function(){
                if(checkFields()){
                    $.post(
                        'test.php', $("#form1").serialize(),
                        function(data){
                            $("#div1").html(data);
                        }
                    );
                }
                else alert("Please fill in name and email fields!");
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
        Name<input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br />
        Email<input type="text" name="email" id="email"><br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Form"> 
    </form>
    <div id="div1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the PHP that it is calling on:

```
<?php
echo "Name: ". $_Request['name'] . "<br />Email:" . $_Request['email'];
?>
```

Comment: Just edited the question, when trying to submit, the alert always pops up regardless of what is in the box, and so it never actually makes it to the $.post part of the script

Comment: Can you post your html code?

Comment: If it always alerts, then your `checkFields` is failing somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function to get the text field value:

```
function checkFields(){
   return ($("#name").val() && $("#email").val());
}
```

The browser doesn't update the `value` attribute when the text is edited. It will also work if you use `.prop('value')`.

Comment: That's a good eye, but please make the reference to `jQuery.val()` more obvious. `$('some.sel').val` could easily be interpreted instead.

Comment: This works! Thank you! I guess the book is just out of date and is using a method that no longer works.